# Why does my call to a method that returns a list, print an empty list?

Tags: java

The method that returns the list, `displayFilesInDirectory()`, prints the entire list when I call `System.out.Println()` from it. However the method that *calls* `displayFilesInDirectory` prints "[]" as the list contents.

```
public  void dropCompleted(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;

    List list = new ArrayList();
    String tableName;
    List listOfDirectories;
    tableName = (String) playList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().getValue();

    if (db.hasFiles()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);

        for (Object file : db.getFiles()) {
            File directories = (File) file;
            listOfDirectories = (displayFilesInDirectory(directories));

            System.out.println("Calling displayFilesInDirectory: " + listOfDirectories);
        }
        success = true;
    }

public static List displayFilesInDirectory(File dir) {
    List newList = new ArrayList();

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            displayFilesInDirectory(file);
        } else if (file.isFile()) {
            newList.add(file);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("From displayFileInDirectory()"+newList);
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: What will you get if your input points to a directory that is empty of files?

Comment: I believe `displayFilesInDirectory()` will just print:`[]`

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example that shows the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you believe it or know it? So what you say in the method displayFilesInDirectory() you have a correct output (for example 4) files. But when you return this list you just printed inside the method, you can't print outside the method? That really seems strange.

Comment: Your displayFilesInDirectory() recurses into directories and displays their contents, but doesn't add those files to the next level up of newList.  So - just a guess - if you start on a directory that only contains directories (maybe the drive root?), the method will display lists of all sub directories, but will return an empty list

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it on a directory with no files directly in that directory, but only in sub-directories of it, `displayFilesInDirectory` will return an empty list because the recursive call on the directories in that directory does not add the resulting list to `newList`.  Replace that line with

```
newList.addAll(displayFilesInDirectory(file));
```

Comment: You added this as an answer as I added the comment :) Upvoting!